# Map network drive to Win7 share from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, windows, drive

To start, I am a complete novice to Ubuntu, and have used Windows exclusively essentially up until a few weeks ago. I am an IT technician working in an MSP, so I am fairly tech savvy.

My goal is to set up my Ubuntu virtual machine and connect it to share coming from the Windows "file server" I have for mass storage. While it was easy enough to install a new virtual machine and get it going, I cannot for the life of me successfully map a network drive from another Windows 7 virtual machine.

I came here as a second resort to Googling it because I've spent more hours than I'd like to admit trying to get it to work, mostly referencing guides that go back as far as 2011. I don't know if Ubuntu command-line formatting has changed at all in recent updates, and that is why I'm experiencing issues? The version on the VM is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I essentially gave and just made an additional Windows 7 VM, as I can map a drive in about 5 seconds, with or without command-line.

Can someone either point me in the direction of an updated guide they have used, or, if it is like Windows in that it is just one command (net use Z: \WIN7-FILE-SVR\MY-SHARE\FOLDER /p:yes), enlighten me to that command? I found similar commands that appeared to be what I'm looking for, but I typically just got cryptic errors I did not understand (again, lack of Ubuntu usage/knowledge)

I imagine this is something one of you will look at and think "Really? This is so easy!" but again please keep in mind my work on Ubuntu is still essentially blindly following guides and entering commands, hoping that the knowledge will start to 'stick'

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the fix here: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-7-samba-errnomem.html

Need to make two registry changes

1) HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters, change "Size" from 1 to 3

2) HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management, change "LargeSystemCache" from 0 to 1

Made the changes, rebooted, and was able to successfully access my Windows 7 shares from the Ubuntu VM

Answer (score 0):

In the Ubuntu file manager adress bar , type :

```
smb://fileserver/share
```

You will be asked for password

Comment: I tried using "smb://win7-file/Storage" but got error "bash: smb://win7-file/Storage/: No such file or directory" I also tried using the IP, same result. Are there any other parameters I need to use?

Comment: Try to install "samba-client" package  if it is not  , but the " smb://server/share" must be typed in the file browser  adress bar  , not in a terminal  (if no adress bar, you may have a "go to server" entry in a file browser menu )   .If you need command line , install smbclient   and search for  syntax examples

Comment: Samba is up to date, trying to access smb://win7-file/Storage/ from file browser now returns "Oops! Something went wrong. Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out"

EDIT: Same error when going to "File > Connect to server" as opposed to "Go > Enter location..."